# How to get data from Mongodb to Angular js

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

i want to display category.json file data into UI as a dropdown list
i have inserted data in mongodb but how to display that data?
i am using Strong loop APIs

Comment: Expose a REST service from your Express app (the E in MEAN) running on your NodeJS server (the N in MEAN), that fetches data from your MongoDb server (the M in MEAN) and sends it as the body of the HTTP response to the Angular application (the A in MEAN).

Comment: I hope you are using loopback..Then you could use Mongodb connector for loopback https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/MongoDB-connector.html